# Replace array inside array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

### The goal

Replace this:

```
(
    [0] => 'Header'
    [1] => 'Body'
)
```

For this:

```
['Header'] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hello!
    )

['Body'] => Array
    (
        [0] => This is the body
    )
```

### The problem

I'm missing the logic and I think this is happening because I doesn't know the syntax.

### The scenario

Follow the original array (preview):

```
Array
(
    [Title] => 'Hello!'
    [Layout] => 'Shared/_Master'
    [Section] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'Header'
            [1] => 'Body'
        )    
)
```

Code:

```
<?php 

$array = [
    'Title' => 'Hello', 
    'Layout' => 'Shared/_Master',
    'Section' => ['Header', 'Body']
    ];

$mineredSection = ['Header' => ['Hello!'], 'Body' => ['This is the body.']];
```

### What did I already tried

I already tried this:

```
foreach ($array['Section'] as $index => $section) {
    $t[$section] = [array_values(array_filter($mineredSection))[$index]];
}

$a = array_replace($array['Section'], $t);

print_r($a);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Header'
    [1] => 'Body'
    ['Header'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello!
        )

    ['Body'] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is the body
        )

)
```

Can someone give me an idea?

Comment: Maybe [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is what you want?

Comment: Maybe. I just doesn't know how to (technically) apply it in my case.

Comment: What is `$this->contents`?

Comment: `$this->contents` is `['Hello', 'This is the body']`. My bad.

Comment: Then you can just do `array_combine($array['Section'], $this->contents);` :-)  P.S. Isn't `$mineredSection` already the array you want?

Comment: `$mineredSection` is just a representation for `$this->contents`. Anyway, it worked — the arrays were combined successfully. But now how can I inject them into `$array['Section']`? By the way, THANK YOU!

Comment: `$array['Section'] = array_combine($array['Section'], $this->contents);`?

Comment: Please, turn your comments into an answer — I need to approve it! Thank you very very much! (My logic to develop is low, hehe =()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).  You pass it two arrays, what you want as the keys and what you want as the values.

```
$array['Section'] = array_combine($array['Section'], $this->contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either this, or I'm not understanding what you're asking

```
$origarr = array('header', 'body');

foreach($origarr as $value){
    if ($value == 'header'){
        $header['header'] = array('hello'); 
    }
    if ($value == 'body'){
        $body['body'] = array('This is the body'); 
    }   
}

var_dump($header);
var_dump($body);
```